# Right procedure when you develop a WP Website for a client

Tags: theme-development, customization

i don't know if this procedure could be incorrect while you develop a WP website for a client, but i worked like this for years:

1. create a database and sub-domain on my server
2. install Wordpress and the relative template
3. start to develop the website
4. When everything is ok for the client export the Website (plus the Database) and import it on client's domain.

Is this procedure "correct"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a suitable method. There are plenty plugins in the WP Plugin Directory that can 'migrate' your site for you including plugins and their settings. All you then have to do is create a database on your clients site (and possibly directory if required) and then import your clients site/files/data.

Another thing you can do if the client site your working on is going on a new domain name / directory that they have never used before you can develop the site live on that domain if you must but I would recommend password protecting the directory until its ready to be viewed publicly.

Answer (score 1):

It would work.
I don't think there really is a right/wrong way to do this.
Whatever works for you and the client is a good way.

However... 
You could do the WP install and everything else on a subdomain of the client.
This way you now if there are any problems with the server the client has and I think that if the website is done you can easily transfer the website to the right folder.
[Like described here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress). 
Scroll down a bit to see "Moving Directories On Your Existing Server"

Answer (score 0):

Lastly, I'm using dublicator WordPress plugin which is really helpful and free. I develop the whole site into my Dev server then I upload installer.php and zip file from Dev server ( I have created those files through dublicator) to client's server.

If you don't want to use any plugin I found this procedure correct!